# All chat.SE links redirected to Area 51

Tags: bug

All chat.SE links redirected to Area 51 starting from the last minute... bug?

(Just click any chat.SE links)

Comment: Indeed, I just noticed this as well. Just as I was about to post a particularly splendid fan art ([this one](http://icpe.tumblr.com/post/164335115339/witcher-3-doodles-176)).